# Import components with Content Porter

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, content-manager

I'm exporting and importing components between different environments successfully with Content Porter. However I have seen that the generated URI are different. Is there any way to import items with the same URI?

SDLTridion 2011 SP1.
SDL Content Porter 2009 SP2.

Comment: I think we can assume you were asking to see if a new imported item can be created with the same URI as its source? Updated items don't change URIs, *new* item URIs are based on the CMS's database (next available or re-using a deleted item), and managed URIs are converted to WebDAV URLs in the porting process.

Comment: As noted by others, it's not possible to do this for new items. Which leaves us with the next question: why do you want to do this? Maybe we can help to solve your real problem.

Comment: I agree with @DominicCronin, the whole idea of using Content Porter is to not have to care about the URIs while porting items, because CP resolves all links for you. That is as long as you make sure to use managed links and don't use URIs in text fields for example.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean TCM URIs, then the answer is no. The TCM URI is unique for each individual Tridion instance and there is no guarantee that an item with TCM URI X from system A is the same item on system B.

Consider the following example: On system A a Content editor creates a new component. It gets ID: tcm:10-**1**-16. On System B, a template developer creates a new Page template. It gets ID: tcm:10-**1**-128. The Content Editor then creates a component on System B with the same content as on system A. However, this component gets ID tcm:10-**2**-16, because the unique number **1** is already given away. This may also vary for each Tridion Item Type as well, but I'm actually not sure about that.

In any case, you see that it is virtually impossible to have the same TCM URIs across environments, unless you migrate the entire Tridion CM database to act as another instance.

It is always possible to have the same WebdavUrls, if the Blueprint (and Publication Titles), Folder Titles, Structure Group Titles and item titles are the same across instances. When developing templates it is therefore always recommended to use WebDAVUrls if you need to fetch items from the Tridion CM through the TOM or Core Service APIs.

Comment: I'm guilty of one hack to get matching TCM URI's at least on Publications by creating new publications in the same order. :-) It's relatively easy to get items by path and name that this isn't really needed. Two other considerations for managing items across CMS environments are "by configuration" (key-value component or AppData to store paths) as well as Content Porter mappings (much less popular).

Answer (score 3):

The only way to keep the same URI is to move the database. Any other method will give you a new URI...

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could also do it by creating exactly the same content in exactly the same order.... but then why have two environments?

Comment: Dominic, that would be interesting but you would have to do EVERYTHING in the same order even user and folder creation. I think a DB copy might be easier... just ;)